# Center text coordinates on screen in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, glew, text-rendering

I'm working on an application that shows text on screen using GLEW and FreeType libraries. I want to center the text on the screen. The problem is, I don't know how to calculate the y coordinates of the given text. I have a list where the text is saved and should be shown on the screen. Each value of the list represents a row that should be printed on the screen. For example if the list contains `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "consectetur adipiscing elit", "sed do eiusmod tempor"` they should be on 3 separate lines. The width of the text, as you can see is variable, but not the height. The height is fixed. I am trying to calculate for each row the x and y coordinates and show them one line at the time. I used this formula to calculate the x coordinates, and it works:

`TEXT_X = (float)DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.width/2.0f - ((float)TEXT_WIDTH/2.0f);`

I'm just taking the width of the monitor, divide it by 2 and subtract the text width (which is just the sum of the width of each character).

Now, for the y coordinates I'll have to start at the half of the monitor height, then add or subtract the text height depending on which line I want to show:

`TEXT_Y = (float)DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.height/2.0f + ...`

I've tried different things and formulas, but I'm just apparently too dumb to figure it out amd I've spent waay too much time on this problem. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

PS: Here is an image of what it should look like at the end (some of the lines are not equal in height, ignore that. I'm not an MS-Paint expert. The red dot represents the center of the screen and the colored squares represent the lines of text to be shown):

[image: example]

Comment: Are you working with a text console or GUI screen? If the latter, what framework / API are you using?

Comment: I am working with GLEW library, sorry I forgot to mention that. My bad

Comment: I usually use a local status variable `y_curr=Ystart` incremented for each line of text `y_curr+=text_height+line_spacing`

Answer (score 0):

How about this (LIVE EXAMPLE):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void centerify_output(std::string str, int num_cols) {
    // Calculate left padding
    int padding_left = (num_cols / 2) - (str.size() / 2);

    // Put padding spaces
    for(int i = 0; i < padding_left; ++i) std::cout << ' ';

    // Print the message
    std::cout << str;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> lines = {
        "---------------------------------",
        "|                               |",
        "|                               |",
        "|         User : xyz            |",
        "|         Pass : ****           |",
        "|                               |",
        "|                               |",
        "---------------------------------",
    };

    int num_cols = 100;

    // VIRTUAL BORDER
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_cols; ++i) std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << '|' << std::endl;

    // OUTPUT
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
        centerify_output(lines[i], num_cols);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // VIRTUAL BORDER
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_cols; ++i) std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << '|' << std::endl;
}
```

### You get the idea. When centring the output vertically, you just put padding end lines at the top of the console.

**Example for WIN:**

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{ 
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    COORD max_size = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize( screen );

    char s[] = "Hello world!";

    COORD pos;
    pos.X = (max_size.X - sizeof(s) ) / 2;
    pos.Y = max_size.Y / 2;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition( screen, pos );

    LPDWORD written;
    WriteConsole( screen, s, sizeof(s), written, 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to keep your application in a console, but want to do some layouts I'd recommend using ncurses as it gives you more control over where you print, and also gives you a possibility to create menus, message boxes and other GUI-like stuff.

ncurses - https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html

Comment: Hmm... In your example you show how to center text in the console, but I need to calculate the coordinates of the text on the display monitor, not in the console.